Typescript is failing to infer an awaited return type
I just want to have a type that dynamically infers the returned object of a promise:
export const props: Props = async ({ groups }) => {
  return {
    id: 123,
    name: groups.name,
  };
};

type InferredProps = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof props>>;

export const component: FC<InferredProps> = ({ id, name }) => {
// ...

But vscode is telling me:

Property 'id' does not exist on type '{}'.
Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.

Yet when I hover over the function arrow in vscode, I get this:
function({ groups }: {
    request: Request;
    groups: URLPatternComponentResult["groups"];
}): Promise<{
    id: number;
    name: string | undefined;
}>

So why is it failing to infer the type correctly even when it can do it there?
I'm expecting it to infer the object correctly so I can use it in the react component...

Don't annotate it with Props? It loses type information. You can use satisfies if you want the value to still match the type but also not override the type information.

@mochaccino you're right. it works when I remove the annotation. thank you!

@mochaccino how can I edit the Props type to make it work how I want tho?

Check out how to use the satisfies keyword in the documentation
